# I need to Build a rest client to make 10k rest api calls/execution of the application in java with best performance. Any useful links will be helpful

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest, asynchronous

Hi i am using Spring 4 Async rest template to make 10k rest api calls to a web service. I have a method that creates the request object and a method that calls the web service. I am using Listenable Future classes and the two methods to create and call are enclosed in another method where the response is handled in future. Any useful links for such a task would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> First, set up your testing environment.
>
> Then benchmark what you have.
>
> Then adjust your code and compare
>
> (repeat as necessary).

Whatever you do, there is a cost associated with it.  You need to be sure that your costs are measured and understood, every step of the way.

A simple Tomcat application might outperform a Spring application or be equivalent depending on what aspects of Spring's inversion of control are being leveraged.  Using a Future might be fast or slow, depending on what it is being compared to.  Using non-NIO might be faster or slower, depending on the implementation and the data being processed.

Comment: Hi. I am looking for an example Rest client in java that makes rest api calls concurrently without waiting for the response from the server. The no of calls that I need to make are 10k. Any example code would help me

Comment: @user8782239 If you are talking about one client, no one client makes simultaneous multiple calls on one network cable.  Either you want multiple processes (10k!) making individual calls once per (some unspecified period of time) or you want one client opening 10k simultaneous connections (with some unknown request pattern), or you want one client making 10k messages on one connection.  If it's supporting 10k sessions, that's pretty easy to do, but not if you must find an example of what to want to do.  You need to know your usage pattern before searching for it.